# Qual é o problema nesse código?

Tags: c#

```
Using System;
Class principal{
  static void Main(){
    Console.Writeline("hello world");
 }
}
```

Eu tentei compilar este código, porém, retorna erro Cs0116 já tentei botar um namespace porém da na mesma, Eu já estou ciente de que não gera erro em outros dispositivos, já li sobre o erro Cs0116 no site da Microsoft, porém independente do código que uso gera sempre o MESMO erro. Eu uso um windows 8.1. não sei o que pode ser, por isso pergunto se pode ser um erro no compilador ou algo do tipo!

Comment: Boas-vindas. Não duplique perguntar, os comentários aqui foram bloqueados para que continue na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/586481/%c3%89-problema-com-o-compilador).